# Comma or semi colon before "always"

Tags: commas, semicolons

Should I use a comma or a semicolon before always? For example,

> I consider my family to be a happy and caring one; always finding the time to share special moments together.

or

> I consider my family to be a happy and caring one, always finding the time to share special moments together.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is wether both clauses stand as independent sentences, which is partially unrelated to whether *always* occurs where it does.

> Independent sentence 1; related independent sentence 2
>
> Sentence 1, dependent clause

Proper use of semicolons is outlined [here](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html).

Comment: As a corollary to this, if you wanted to use a semicolon you would say something like "I consider my family to be a happy and caring one; we always find the time to share special moments together."